# USB Issues - WD19TB dock - Dell XPS 15 laptop - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: usb, 20.04, mouse, dell, thunderbolt

I have a Dell XPS 15 (4K OLED) running Ubuntu 20.04 connected to the Dell WD19TB dock.

The dock has connected to it:

- 2x4K external displays
- Ethernet
- USB receiver for my wireless keyboard/mouse

It mostly works (ignoring fractional scaling weirdness). The main issue I have is that sometimes the USB drops meaning my keyboard/mouse stop working. Sometimes its just for a couple of seconds, other times I need to reboot my machine or plug/unplug the dock. I already have "No Security" set for Thunderbolt and Ubuntu shows the dock as "Authorised". I'm unsure how to proceed.

Thanks,
Gordon

EDIT: Same hardware fine on Mac OS X (13" MBP with 4 Thunderbolt Ports).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like powertop --auto-tune was causing USB autosuspend to occur when it shouldn't. Disabling powertop seems to have resolve it.